What can I do to create the Quicksight Cudos v5 dashboard?
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      python: 3.x
    commands:
      # Install any required dependencies if needed
      echo Installing dependencies...
  
  pre_build:
    commands:
      # Navigate to the directory where the YAML file is located
      echo Navigating to the directory containing the YAML file...
  
  build:
    commands:
      # Create the QuickSight dashboard using the YAML file
      echo Creating QuickSight dashboard...
      aws quicksight create-dashboard \
        --aws-account-id awsaccountid \
        --dashboard-id cudos-v5 \
        --name "CUDOS Dashboard v5" \
        --source-entity file://CUDOS-v5.yaml
  
  post_build:
    commands:
      echo QuickSight dashboard creation complete.

artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'


I am using this as my buildspec-publish.yml. However, I have kept all my resources on the same directory. The CUDOS-v5.yml I have, is from "https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cudos-framework-deployment/blob/main/dashboards/cudos/CUDOS-v5.yaml".
I have also used entered the dataset ids for the corresponding dataset:
- hourly_view
- resource_view
- summary_view
Still I am failing to create the dashboard. Help me solve the issue.
